# parsing nested JSON data, and saving into Realm DB in nadroid

Tags: android, realm

I am new to android and Realm DB.I am not getting how to parse nested JSON data and save into Realm

I have JSON Array-

```
[{ _id: 583d45e1ee31662334c0d63e,
senderUsername: '7411271012',
senderUserId: '4',
senderDisplayName: 'Santosh',
messages: '',
sendDate: 'November 29th 2016, 2:39:53 pm',
groupId: '1',
groupName: 
 { groupName: 'XYZ Support',
   GroupDisplayName: 'XYZZ Support' },
category: 'UtoG',
messageType: 'message',
fileName: '',
__v: 0 } ]
```

I created two model classes

```
public class **myChatFeed** extends RealmObject {
@PrimaryKey
private String _id;
private String senderUsername;
private String senderUserId;
private String senderDisplayName;
private String messages;
private String sendDate;
private String groupId;
private groupNames groupName;
private String category;
private String messageType;
private String fileName;
private String __v;
> Getter and Setters >
```

}

```
public class **groupNames** extends RealmObject {

private String groupName;
private String GroupDisplayName;
<>Getters and Setters<>
```

}

this is code to insert into Realm

```
realm.beginTransaction();           
realm.createOrUpdateAllFromJson(myChatFeed.class,jsonArrayData);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

When i execute this, inner JSON object will not save
showing o/p: groupName:null, where as all other fields getting saved.

any help ../??

Comment: your json is not valid

Comment: updated JSON data

Comment: How do you determine `groupNames` is `null`. You cannot trust the debugger for that information. Your code looks valid otherwise.

Comment: i am displaying the result, once the json data saved into realm.
RealmResults<myChatFeed> res = realm.where(myChatFeed.class).findAll();
                JsonDataTextView.setText(res.toString());

Comment: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#json